# PermissionError when running Django functional tests using FireFox ESR in a virtualenv on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, virtualenv

I've been slowly working my way through the excellent "Obey the Testing Goat" book on Test Driven Development, and as I hit the end of chapter 7, I noticed the author has put out an updated version.  In the updated version, the author recommends using a virtualenv from the very beginning, so I decided to update my current code to work in a virtualenv, and to switch from a Windows to Linux environment at the same time.  My issue is when running my (previously working) functional tests, I end up with "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied" on line 3 below

```
def setUp(self):
    binary = FirefoxBinary(r'/home/spa/firefox') 
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

I have full access to the files in question, so I'm thinking it may be an issue as I'm calling the function from a virtualenv, and I have no clue how that effects permissions.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue ended up being unrelated to the VirtualEnv - simply changing the path of the FireFoxBinary to '/home/spa/firefox/firefox' fixed the issue; it seems that the binary is unable to read inside the firefox folder, so you have to point it directly to the binary.